# Unclear Document regarding AEM form validation

Tags: validation, aem

Hi everyone wonder if anyone can provide pictures or the exact steps pertaining to how to locate the "validation expression according to this link https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/forms/using/adaptive-form-expressions.html#main-pars_header_3

Also while you are here I am wondering if it is possible to use these validation tools to check if the income is greater than the cost. i.e the user have to key in a higher value in the income numeric box as compared to the cost numeric box. If not providing a guide that allows me to do this would be great.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The validate expression is written using the **Code editor** of the rule editor. For e.g., I've created an adaptive form with 2 **Numeric Boxes** (Income and Cost) as shown below.

[image]

So, to validate if the value entered in the income is always greater than the cost, then click on the Income field and then click the **Edit Rules** icon. This will open the rule editor

[image]

Once in the rule editor window, click on the Income field on the left rail and then click the Create button.

[image]

In the Create Rule window, you can use the Validate event and configure the required condition.

[image]

You may also need to write a similar condition on the cost field as well, but in reverse (Cost is less than Income) so that when someone changes the value in the Cost field, it is validated too.

As far as your original question goes, if you switch to the **Code Editor**, it should give you another editor where you can write Javascript to validate the value. The validation expression from your documentation link goes there (see below).

[image]